# Get result from an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to check ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION with registerForActivityResult And this code does't work, when i check the permission the Toast "Ok" does't appear

`mStartForResult.launch(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION));`

````
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Ok",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `Intent` action [is not documented to return anything](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION). So, you will never get `Activity.RESULT_OK`.

Comment: So How do i know that the permission is checked or not please ?

Comment: @dani: Call [`canDrawOverlays()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#canDrawOverlays(android.content.Context)), presumably.

Comment: ok i will try it .